# jpa one-to-many self reference is fetching all levels

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I'm trying to create a social app service. I have user with confirmed or nonconfirmed relationships.

When I load UserA, the result look like belove.

```
   "result":{  
      "idUser":"UserA",
      "unconFriendships":[  
         {  
            "idUser":"UserB",
            "unconFriendships":[  
               {  
                  "idUser":"UserC",
                  "unconFriendships":[ 
                      ...
```

While it has to be look like

```
   "result":{  
      "idUser":"UserA",
      "unconFriendships":[  
         {  
            "idUser":"UserB",
            "unconFriendships":null //only one level have to fetched
                   ....
```

I thought that this was because jackson json library, I debbuged the code. Before serialization, I inspected userA object and I saw that `userA.unconFriendships.userB.unconFriendships` was not `null` and with `size` bigger than 0.

Nearly it has been 12 hours, still couldn't solve the problem. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advence.

Here is UserEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aduser",uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"idUser","nmEmail"}))
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="cdUser")
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {

    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 8864033727886664353L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "admin_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "admin_seq", sequenceName = "CDUSER_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name="cdUser")
    private long cdUser;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", targetEntity=Friendship.class)
    @JsonProperty
    protected Set<UnconfirmedFriendship> unconFriendships;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", targetEntity=Friendship.class)
    @JsonProperty
    protected Set<UnconfirmedFriendship> conFriendships;
...
```

Friendship.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aduserfriend")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "verified")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="friend_cduser",scope=UserEntity.class)
public abstract class Friendship extends BaseEntity{

    protected static final long serialVersionUID = -670863816551430192L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "cdFriendship")
    private long cdFriendship;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_cduser")
    protected UserEntity owner;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "friend_cduser")
    protected UserEntity friend;

    @Column(name = "verified",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private boolean verified;
...
```

UnconfirmedFriendship.java and ConfirmedFriendship.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "0")//this value is 1 for Confirmed relationship
public class UnconfirmedFriendship extends Friendship {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 57796452166904132L;
}
```

Comment: please show your repository (or other fetching method) code