# JPA Hibernate: How to limit fetch depth for a self referencing entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I will write an example just to reduce the complexity:

---

Human.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "human")
@DynamicInsert(value = true)
@DynamicUpdate(value = true)
public class Human {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Human parent;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy ="parent")
    private Collection<Human> children;

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

---

HumanDao.java

```
@Repository
public interface HumanDao  extends CrudRepository<Human, Long>{
    @Query(value = 
            "SELECT * " +
            "FROM humans " + 
            "WHERE parent_id = ?1",
            nativeQuery = true)
    public Iterable<Human> getChildren(Long parentId);

}
```

---

TestClass.java

```
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    private HumanDao dao;

    public void test(Long parentId) {
        Iterable<Human> children = dao.getChildren(parentId);
        System.out.println(children);
    }
}
```

---

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.max_fetch_depth=1
```

---

Database:

```
ID | Name | Parent
1  | Mike | null
2  | John | 1
3  | Bill | 2
4  | Carl | 3
```

---

Problem: When I getChildren for Mike, I expect to see only John there, but I get all the references up to Carl included.

How can I limit the depth of this self referencing entity so it doesn't go deeper than a specified number limit.

I constructed my entity following [this example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping) (step 3)

Update: I found someone with a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574093/jpa-one-to-many-self-reference-is-fetching-all-levels), but he didn't solve it either.

Comment: My temporary solution was giving up on the "children" field. I will get an array of Human every time I call HumanDao.getChildren().

Comment: Hibernate is not the one fetching the other children. If your problem is similar to the one you linked to, then it's your JSON marshaller that serializes the Human, thus calls getChildren(), which thus lazy-loads the children, which get marshalled, which thus calls their getChildren() method, etc. So the solution is in configuring your JSON marshaller (if Jackson, use JsonIgnore, or use the hibernate module and configure it to not marshal the uninitialized proxies, of transform the entity to a DTO, suitable for JSON marshalling.

Comment: This was a basic example, that's why it looks unprofessional. I am checking the children fields with the debugger before they get a chance to be marshaled, and they are already there. I can also see multiple queries being made with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`.

Comment: Looking at the children with the debugger will also make Hibernate lazy load the children. Are you sure the SQL queries that you see being logged are logged *before* the Himan is marshalled? What happens if you put a breakpoint right after the execution of the query, and see how many queries are logged at this point? What happend if you JsonIgnore the children? Also, why are you using a native query rather than a JPQL query?

Comment: I needed a quick fix so I no longer remember what the situation was back then. I've given up on the children fields as stated in the first comment.
I also didn't know what arguments should the @Query annotation get. All the examples I've read used that argument.